# MATLAB Erlang B-Formula

Tags: matlab

How can I write Erlang B Formula as you see below in MATLAB?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWdbJ.jpg]

I have tried;

```
     GOS=((A.^C)/factorial(C))/...
```

but couldn't complete it. Thnx anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `A` and `C` are scalars, you can use:

```
GOS = A.^C/factorial(C) / sum(A.^[0:C] ./ factorial([0:C])).
```

Comment: @smlnl: Are `A` and `C` both scalars?  The code works for me on both Matlab and Octave (note the edit with `./` that I put in a while ago).

Comment: @smlnl: I don't understand your comment about changing `sum(A.^[0:C])`.  What did you change it to?  What was `A` set to?

Comment: GOS = A.^C/factorial(C) / sum(A.^[0:C] ./ factorial([0:C])) to GOS = A.^C/factorial(C) / 45 and it worked.

Comment: @smlnl: If you change the `A` in the denominator to `repmat(A, 1, C + 1)`, does that work?

Comment: No. Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.

Comment: @smlnl: What are `A` and `C` in your test case?  What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: version is R2010a. A is float number and C is an integer.

Comment: @smlnl: I was trying with A as an integer, but trying with a float made my formula still work.  I am also using R2010a.  Do you know specifically what subexpression is failing?  Could you please post the particular values of `A` and `C` you were using for testing?

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your detailed answers. I think I'm missing somepoint so I'm sleepy :) With a well-rested brain, I think I'm gonna solve that stupid thing. :) Thank you very much.